# Animating Canvas Stroke

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm looking for a way to animate the drawing of a stroke with HTML canvas.

Is there anything pre-defined that allows you to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know any pre-defined solution. Maybe in a lib. like [raphael](http://raphaeljs.com/)

But if you know your stroke (x,y-positions of the pixels). You can set the x and y position in an array and use the array for the animation of painting a stroke...

Comment: Thanks for your response Mika, so I'd have to draw the stroke a bit at a time using a setInterval to go through each item in the array? Rather than being able to animate the drawing of the stroke?

Comment: Or use requestAnimationFrame (http://paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/) if you support only newer browser